# Store and query a list of string in gae datastore with Java

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I try to store in the gae datastore an array of string within an Entity. Something like that:

```
public class MyClass {
  private String id;
  private String name;
  (...)
  private List<String> tags;
  (...)
}

Entity entity = new Entity("MyClass", "myId");
entity.setProperty("name", "My Name");
List<String> tags = new ArrayList<String>();
tags.add("gae");
tags.add("datastore");
entity.setProperty("tags", tags);
```

Is this approach the correct one and how to use the tags property in queries (for example, all elements that have the value gae in the tags list)?

```
Query query = new Query("MyClass");
query.addFilter(fieldName, FilterOperator.EQUAL, "gae");
Iterable<Entity> result = datastore.prepare(q).asIterable();
for (Entity entity : result) {
  (...)
}
```

Thanks for your help!
Thierry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes thats right, if your *tags* list doesn't get to big, (more then 10k, have a look at the field size [limits](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/entities#Properties_and_Value_Types))

you can query now you MyClass like this:

```
Query q = new Query("myClass")
                .addFilter("tags",
                           Query.FilterOperator.EQUAL,
                           "gae");
```